# C++ SQLBindParameter

Tags: c++, odbc

Here are the declarations of the variables:

```
string strFirstName;
string strLastName;
string strAddress;
string strCity;
string strState;
double dblSalary;
string strGender;
int intAge;
```

...Do some "cin" statements to get data...

```
retcode = SQLPrepare(StatementHandle, (SQLCHAR *)"INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE ([FirstName], [LastName], [Address], [City], [State], [Salary], [Gender],[Age]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", SQL_NTS);

retcode = SQLBindParameter(StatementHandle, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_LONGVARCHAR, 50, 0 &strFirstName,0, NULL);

retcode = SQLBindParameter(StatementHandle, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_LONGVARCHAR, 50, 0, &strLastName,0, NULL);

retcode = SQLBindParameter(StatementHandle, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_LONGVARCHAR, 30, 0, &strAddress,0, NULL);

retcode = SQLBindParameter(StatementHandle, 4, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_LONGVARCHAR, 30, 0, &strCity,0, NULL);

retcode = SQLBindParameter(StatementHandle, 5, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_LONGVARCHAR, 3, 0, &strState,0, NULL);

retcode = SQLBindParameter(StatementHandle, 6, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_DOUBLE, SQL_DOUBLE, 0, 0, &dblSalary,0, NULL);

retcode = SQLBindParameter(StatementHandle, 7, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_LONGVARCHAR, 2, 0, &strGender,0, NULL);

retcode = SQLBindParameter(StatementHandle, 8, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_LONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &intAge,0, NULL);

retcode = SQLExecute(StatementHandle);
```

The int and double work fine and get stored in the table...but I can't figure out how to get the strings to store...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[MSDN documentation for SQLBindParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710963.aspx) says you are meant to pass a buffer containing the data for `ParameterValuePtr` and the length of the buffer in bytes for `BufferLength`:

```
retcode = SQLBindParameter(StatementHandle, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR,
   SQL_LONGVARCHAR, 50, 0, strFirstName.c_str(), strFirstName.length(), NULL);
```

> ParameterValuePtr [Deferred Input] A
>   pointer to a buffer for the
>   parameter's data. For more
>   information, see "ParameterValuePtr
>   Argument" in "Comments."
>
> BufferLength [Input/Output] Length of
>   the ParameterValuePtr buffer in bytes.
>   For more information, see
>   "BufferLength Argument" in "Comments."

Comment: very close...:)  Thanks!

retcode = SQLBindParameter(StatementHandle, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_LONGVARCHAR, 50, 0, (SQLPOINTER) strFirstName.c_str(), strFirstName.length(), NULL);

Comment: what meant by pass two different data type? ex. SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_LONGVARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the api, wants an **unsigned char ***
try passing in a c string, using the **c_str()** method call.

Comment: SQLPOINTER ParameterValuePtr

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710963.aspx