# SQL Server ODBC String data, right truncation for DateTime and Binary Inserts

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

BufLenI anoUsing ODBC to INSERT data to a SQL server 2012 (Express) database I am getting a truncations message:

After reading this:

["String data, right truncation" warning on a select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458550/string-data-right-truncation-warning-on-a-select-statement)

I checked and Regional settings are not enabled

When I insert a datetime using a query:

INSERT INTO Orders ( UpdatedDT ) VALUES ( '02-06-2014T10:41:49') 
All is good.

When I try binding a string like this:

[C++ SQLBindParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176459/c-sqlbindparameter)

```
iRetVal = SQLBindParameter( hStmt, Col, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_C_CHAR, ColSz, 0, pBuf, BufLen, pBufLen) )
```

or

```
iRetVal = SQLBindParameter( hStmt, Col, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, SQL_C_BINARY, ColSz, 0, pBuf, BufLen, pBufLen )
```

I get the relentless ODBC error message:

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right truncation

I have looked at castings but I am not sure if this is the problem

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

I am stumped.

I have studied the API call carefully here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I can insert with my code if I only bind integer data types of fixed lengths

In checking here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

It seems that the conversion is implicit so I do not understand why I get a truncation error.

I have the same problem with binary date being written to a VarBinary(MAX) column.

I am using ODBC Driver 14 I believe and DSN or connection string I get the same issue.

```
CREATE TABLE MyFrustratingTable
(
    PK INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    UpdatedDT datetime,
    UpdatedU INT,
    DataBlob varbinary(MAX),
)
```

ADDED:

BufLen is an INT that contains the length of the binary data pointed to by pBuf. Colsz contains the same number but I have experimented with larger and smaller numbers in any and all combinations.

Comment: You might want to show what is in BufLen or it is meaningless as it could be 1.

Comment: Your still not showing us the info we need. In your first SQLBindParameter call what number is in ColSz and what is in *pBufLen. Also why is the 2nd last argument 0 - it should not be.

Comment: Late night long day error. Corrected